# How to filter null value in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a situation in my sql statement. In this sql statement, **I joined 3 tables together (Application_Detail, Teacher_Detail, and Class_Detail),** and than I used `WHERE` to filter my table to find out how many teacher used this application, I found the following result.

As you can see in the 1st record, both teacher related and class related field are null. I am wondering is there a way to filter out the 1st record and only show the 2,3,4 record? because I want to only want to show the record if there are some value in teacherId, teacherName, class, or grade column.

```
   teacherId teacherName   applicationName  class   grade
1. NULL      NULL         Excel            NULL     NULL
2. 5         NULL         Excel            NULL     NULL
3. NULL      NULL         Excel            A        6
4  NULL      NULL         Excel            B        2
```

Here is my SQL command

```
SELECT
   td.teacherId,
   teacherName,
   applicationName,
   class,
   grade
FROM
   [AppUser_Detail] as aud
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Teacher_Detail] as td ON aud.teacherId = td.teacherId
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Application_Detail] as ad ON aud.applicationId = ad.applicationId
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Class_Detail] as cd ON aud.classId = cd.classId
WHERE
aud.applicationId = 6 //I filter if my application Id is 6
```

Comment: you can check for :``teacherId IS NOT NULL OR classId is Not NULL``

Comment: Try this - `WHERE aud.applicationId = 6 and (td.teacherId is not null OR class is not null OR  grade is not null)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   td.teacherId,
   teacherName,
   applicationName,
   class,
   grade
FROM
   [AppUser_Detail] as aud
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Teacher_Detail] as td ON aud.teacherId = td.teacherId
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Application_Detail] as ad ON aud.applicationId = ad.applicationId
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Class_Detail] as cd ON aud.classId = cd.classId
WHERE
td.teacherId is not null OR class is not null OR grade is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   td.teacherId,
   teacherName,
   applicationName,
   class,
   grade
FROM [AppUser_Detail] as aud
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Teacher_Detail] as td ON aud.teacherId = td.teacherId
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Application_Detail] as ad ON aud.applicationId = ad.applicationId
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Class_Detail] as cd ON aud.classId = cd.classId
WHERE
aud.applicationId = 6 //I filter if my application Id is 6 
AND NOT (td.teacherId IS NULL AND class IS NULL AND grade IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT td.teacherId AS [TeacherID]
        ,teacherName AS [TeacherName]
        ,applicationName AS [ApplicationName]
        ,class AS [Class]
        ,grade AS [Grade]
    FROM [AppUser_Detail] AS aud
    LEFT JOIN [Teacher_Detail] AS td ON aud.teacherId = td.teacherId
    LEFT JOIN [Application_Detail] AS ad ON aud.applicationId = ad.applicationId
    LEFT JOIN [Class_Detail] AS cd ON aud.classId = cd.classId
    WHERE aud.applicationId = 6
    )
WHERE TeacherID IS NOT NULL
    OR TeacherName IS NOT NULL
    OR Grade IS NOT NULL
```